# Batch use a string as an active console command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console, windows-scripting

My trouble is to read a string from `test.txt` and type it in as a console command.

Example:
user is asked to provide a path to their sandbox folder and at the same time in a console it is already offered (from a saved `test.txt`), only waiting for the user to hit ENTER

```
Path to your sandboxes folder: C:\Whatever\Path\Sandboxes
```

Where `Path to your sandboxes folder:` is part of a `set /p` command in a script waiting for an input; and `C:\Whatever\Path\Sandboxes` has been typed-in by the script as a pre-offered path. From here the user can either hit ENTER, if satisfied with offered path or edit it: `C:\Whatever\OtherPath\Sandcastles`

I assume, the first step would be to read from `test.txt` into a variable, but how do I proceed from there? How do i type the characters of this string variable into a console?

Comment: Unless you can handle single letter commands you need to display the string using `echo` then if the user enters nothing use the displayed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By combining it with cscript.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (test.txt) do set "output=%%I"
  CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%output%"
  set /P "var=Path to your sandboxes folder: "
  echo selected path = %var%
  goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Worked like charm! `""%%i""` always created additional `""""` when tested with empty user input, but in general, it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @ClarkYeah I amended the script to not do the double quotes when no variable is selected from file.

Answer (score 0):

not possible with pure batch, but you can use a default value (because `set /p` doesn't touch the variable, when you just press ENTER):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  set "folder=%%b"
  set /p "folder=%%a (ENTER for default [%%b]) : "
)
echo "%folder%"
```

Note: there is a space at the start of the `%folder%`. Easy to avoid, when you remove the space from `test.txt`:

```
Path to your sandboxes folder:C:\Whatever\Path\Sandboxes
```

Answer (score -2):

If in said `test.txt` the first line only contains the default path, you could use this:

```bat
SET /P _path=<test.txt
SET /P _path=%_path%
```

This is the fastest way to achieve this, but it only works with the 1st line ([read more](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)).

---

If it is e.g. in the 3rd line use this:

```bat
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%G IN ("C:\adjust\path\test.txt") DO (SET "_path=%%G" & GOTO break)
:break

SET /P _path=%_path%
```

For the 5th line change `skip=2` to `skip=4`, for the 17th line to `skip=16`; basically if the path is in line `n` you want to skip `n-1` lines.

You could also use `FINDSTR`, but this is unecessary as long as the location of the path in `test.txt` is known.